# Android tabs : Don't swipe tabs until current tab is filled

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I have an android app where i have 3 tabs for each of the following in order- child's details(tab1),father's details(tab2) ,mother's details(tab3). The user should not be able to swipe to tab2 unless tab1 is filled completely. How do i implement this ?

Comment: I **strongly** recommend using the wizard pattern instead of tabs. Showing tabs tells the user "hey, you can go wherever you want". That is not the flow you have in mind, and your attempts to prevent the user from navigating the tabs will frustrate the user. There are [several libraries that implement the wizard UI pattern](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/131).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to limit the adapter size until the tab was loaded.